# Book about miniaturization and reading thoughts

Tags: story-identification, books

I've read a book in the past about I believe an American scientist that has found a technology to read thoughts (eventually to connect brains,) but his research didn't go well.

He was taken to Russia, I believe, to help extract the thoughts of a person by miniaturizing a ship with some scientists and his brain connection machines. It turned out the person had a dead brain.

It was unsuccessful because the person was dead but it proved his technology to be useful to help people connect their brains. At the end he escaped and both countries exchanged technologies in this way preventing one side to have a significant advantage over the other.

I'm not sure if the book was Russian or American, nor the author.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall any details of the cover?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is [Fantastic Voyage II: Destination Brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Voyage_II:_Destination_Brain) by Isaac Asimov.

[image: Book cover]

From Wikipedia.

> One Soviet scientist, Pyotor Leonovich Shapirov, a pioneer of the miniaturization process, had spoken vaguely of a way to make it affordable. Unfortunately, he now lies in a coma, with his secrets apparently locked away forever.

> But Shapirov had been acquainted with an American scientist, Albert Jonas Morrison, who has his own peculiar theories regarding the brain's processing and storage of creative thought. Shapirov had been greatly intrigued by Morrison's ideas, and it's this interest that led the Soviets to turn to Morrison for help.

> After a great deal of coercion, Morrison agrees to be miniaturized along with four Soviet scientists, enter Shapirov's dying brain, and attempt to use his computer program to retrieve the thoughts contained therein.

Comment: As for the nationality of the author, Asimov was born in Russia but his family moved to the US when he was 3 years old, and he never learned Russian.